# MySQL prepared statement returns a NULL value

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a MYSQL prepared statement to query my database but I'm not getting the results i'm after.  `var_dump` returns a NULL value. Here's my code

**UPDATE with full code and error**

```
function dynamicsearch() {
    $link = mysqli_connect ( '192.168.2.113', 'root', '', 'solstats' );

    if (isset ( $_POST ['callerID'] )) {
        $number = $_POST ['callerID'];
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM call_outcome WHERE callerid LIKE '?' LIMIT 10";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare ( $link, $qry );
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $number);
        $stmt->execute ();
        var_dump($stmt);
        $res = $stmt->fetch ();
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $res );
        return $res;

    }
}


var_dump ( $res );
$IDdata = dynamicsearch ();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>DB Query Results</h2>
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>callerid</th>
            <th>calldate</th>
            <th>ivron</th>
            <th>bopon</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>uniqueid</th>
            <th>queue_name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
<?php
while ( $result = mysqli_fetch_array ( $IDdata ) ) { // Fecth array used to fetch each array of the queried result and populate it to the table.
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $result ['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result ['callerid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result ['calldate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result ['ivron'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result ['bopon'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result ['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result ['uniqueid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result ['queue_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong.I did another `var_dump` after the statement is executed and it returned the following error `object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (0) { }` . What does this error mean and how can I fix it ? Thanks.

[image: Error]

Comment: You have to bind parameters before execute. use `bind_param()` method.

Comment: Updated the original OP please have a look as im still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your not passing it the value.

```
   $number = $_POST ['callerID'];
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM call_outcome WHERE callerid LIKE ? LIMIT 10";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare ( $link, $qry );
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $number); 
        $stmt->execute ();
        $res = $stmt->fetch ();
```

I haven't worked with mysqli, might want to double check that.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: I just tried that with no effect, both errors are still showing.

Comment: Check now just updated, that was PDO syntax before, sorry about that.

Comment: Is there any error reporting on? The reason the SQL didn't return results is definitely the parameter not being passed in. I'm thinking the spaces between the execute and parenthesis might be causing syntax error. Could also be callerid is a string? Maybe cast it `$number = (int)$_POST ['callerID'];`

Comment: you need to mention the data type of your callerid field in bind_param function

Comment: @KarthickKumar, isn't the 'i' the data type?

Comment: if the data type is string you need to mention it as 's'

Comment: Oh, yea guess it makes sense it is a string since OP is using like, oops.

Comment: Using command line so don't have debugging but as per your other suggestions tried them both with no effect. Thanks for your suggestions I appreciate them.

Comment: I think @KarthickKumar answer is right. I thought your `callerID` was an int which is what the `i` in that bindparam is for. It probably is a string though so you'll need the `s` as Karthick suggested.

Comment: I've just tried with an `s` instead of and `i` but that made no difference either, could the problem be elsewhere? How could I check this?

Comment: Try removing all the spaces between your calls e.g. `$stmt->execute ();` should be `$stmt->execute();` and `$_POST ['callerID'];` should be `$_POST['callerID'];`.

Comment: The spaces are added by eclipse when I format the code, I tried removing them to no avail. I have edited the OP with the full code and Error hopefully you can spot something I cant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72757/discussion-between-chris85-and-user2268970).

Answer (score 0):

please check this updated code :

```
        function dynamicsearch() {
    $link = mysqli_connect ( '192.168.2.113', 'root', '', 'solstats' );

    if (isset ( $_POST ['callerID'] )) {
        $number = $_POST ['callerID'];
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM call_outcome WHERE callerid LIKE '%?%' LIMIT 10";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare ( $link, $qry );
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $number); //for integer use i , for string use s
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $res= mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);       
        return $res;

    }
}
```

Comment: This has been suggested before and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: i think you are mixing both procedural and object oriented method of mysqli

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit before, I just tried it and it doesn't load anything not even var_dump errors. I'm using php 5.1 so I think some of your syntax isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function dynamicsearch() {
    $link = mysqli_connect('192.168.2.113', 'root', '', 'solstats');
    $result = array();
    if (isset($_POST ['callerID'])) {
        $number = $_POST ['callerID'];
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM call_outcome WHERE callerid LIKE ? LIMIT 10";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $qry);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $number);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $callerid, $calldate, $ivron, $bopon, $type, $uniqueid, $queue_name);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $result[] = ['id' => $id, 'callerid' => $callerid, 'calldate' => $calldate, 'ivron' => $ivron,
                'bopon' => $bopon, 'type' => $type, 'uniqueid' => $uniqueid, 'queue_name' => $queue_name];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$IDdata = dynamicsearch();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>DB Query Results</h2>
        <table border="2">
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>callerid</th>
                <th>calldate</th>
                <th>ivron</th>
                <th>bopon</th>
                <th>type</th>
                <th>uniqueid</th>
                <th>queue_name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>        
                <?php
                foreach ($IDdata as $result) { // Fecth array used to fetch each array of the queried result and populate it to the table.
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result ['id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result ['callerid'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result ['calldate'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result ['ivron'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result ['bopon'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result ['type'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result ['uniqueid'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result ['queue_name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion. I have just tried this the page doesn't load anything. Does `mysqli_stmt` work in PHP 5.1???

Comment: No. All functions came with php 5. Please use `$number = "%".$_POST ['callerID']."%";` instead of `$number = $_POST ['callerID'];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72782/discussion-between-eranda-and-user2268970).